# Auto-fill form on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, autofill

I am using the Scripts n Styles plugin with this code to auto-fill a logged in user's email into form on WordPress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementsByName("Element-Name")[0].value = "<?php $current_user->user_email ?>";
}
</script>
```

However, when I refresh the page I get the following text (the quoted value in the code above) instead of the actual value.

```
<?php $current_user->user_email ?>
```

Any idea what I am missing here? Is this an issue with the plugin?

Comment: Scripts n Styles does NOT run PHP that is inside of the JavaScript fields. This won't work. You'll need to use a different plugin that handles user supplied PHP, or edit the theme's function file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that you don't output anything. 
Try

```
<?php echo $current_user->user_email; ?>
```

But in your example it should have been just an empty value. There is something fishy with the PHP parser not detecting the PHP part.

Comment: You are right. Adding echo to the code does not fill the form with the actual value, instead the form is populated with <?php echo $current_user->user_email; ?>